# Galois Group of an Extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, galois-theory

> **Question:** Determine the isomorphism type of $ \mathrm{Gal}\,(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{2},i)/\mathbb{Q}(i)) $.

$\\$

This amounts to finding isomorphisms that send $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{2},i)$ to itself and also fix elements in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

I know that $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{2},i)/\mathbb{Q}(i)) \leq \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{2},i)/\mathbb{Q})$ which means that if we take a typical element $a+bi \in \mathbb{Q}(i)$ and $\sigma \in \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{2},i)/\mathbb{Q}(i))$ then $\sigma(a+bi) = a+bi$.

Using the tower theorem I know that $|\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{2},i)/\mathbb{Q}(i))|=8$; hence using classification we know that the group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_8,\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4,$ or $\ \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$.

I think I need to first determine a vector space basis for the extension $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{2},i)/\mathbb{Q}(i)$. I think it is just $\{1,\alpha,(\alpha)^2,...,(\alpha)^7\}$ where $\alpha = \sqrt[8]{2}$.

Thus for any $\beta \in K/\mathbb{Q}(i)$ we have $\beta = a_0+a_1 \alpha+ \cdots a_7(\alpha)^7$ where $a_j \in \mathbb{Q}(i)$ for $j\in\{0,\dots,7\}$. From here I can just take any $\gamma \in \text{Gal}(K\mathbb{Q}(i))$ and see that $\gamma$ is completely determined by where it sends $\alpha$; hence the group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_8$.

I am not sure whether this logic is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need an additional argument to show that the Galois group is $\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z$.  The statement you use to justify it is that any element of the Galois group is determined by its action on $\sqrt[8]{2}$.  This is true for any primitive element generating an extension, and in particular it is true for extensions with non-cyclic Galois group.  For instance, elements of $\operatorname{Gal}(\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})/\Bbb Q)$ are determined by their action on $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$, but the Galois group can be shown to be the elementary abelian group $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ instead of $\Bbb Z/4 \Bbb Z$.

In your case, you need to show the existence of an automorphism that **cyclically** permutes the roots of $x^8 - 2$.  A good guess would be the automorphism $\sigma$ uniquely determined by sending $\sqrt[8]{2}$ to $\zeta_8\sqrt[8]{2}$, where $\zeta_8$ is a primitive 8-th root of unity.  Note that $\zeta_8\not\in \Bbb Q(i)$, so $\sigma(\zeta_8\sqrt[8]{2}) \ne \zeta_8^2\sqrt[8]{2}$.  You need to compute what $\sigma$ does to $\zeta_8$ before you can demonstrate that $\sigma$ is a generator for the Galois group.

Comment: $\omega_8 = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} i$ so when applying $\sigma$ to it, I will need to know what $\sigma(\sqrt{2})$ =? since everything else is fixed. Correct?

Comment: @Rod exactly right (note also that this description of $\omega_8$ is the reason why $x^8-2$ splits in $\Bbb(Q(\sqrt[8]{2},i)$).

Comment: No, sorry if $\sqrt[8]{2} \mapsto \omega_8 \sqrt[8]{2}$ then $\sqrt{2} \mapsto (\omega_8 \sqrt[8]{2})^4=-\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Cool, just finished it, THanks a lot!

Comment: Using this same map, if I consider Gal$(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{2},i)/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}))$ I get that we can have a map of order $8$ since $\omega_8 \mapsto \omega^7$ or $\omega_8$ since $i \mapsto \pm i$. It is in the case that when $\omega_8 \mapsto \omega_8$ the automorphism that takes $\sqrt[8]{2} \mapsto \omega_8\sqrt[8]{2}$ will have order $8$, so again I get $\mathbb{Z}_8$?

Comment: The Galois group will not be cyclic in this case.  Note that there are (at least) two intermediate fields $K$ with $|K:\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})| = 2$, namely $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2})$ and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2}, i)$.  Thus the Galois group has at least two subgroups of index 2.

Comment: Ah okay, this is just the correspondence. Okay thanks a lot. I think I can go from here.

Comment: Yes, that was an overlook on my part.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Considering $f(x) = x^8 -2$ and $a = \sqrt[8] 2$, we have that if $\xi \neq 1$ is a $8$-th root of unit then $a,-a, ai, -ai,a\xi, a\xi^3, a\xi^5,a \xi^7$ are the eight distinct roots of $f$.

Now any $\sigma \in \mathrm {Aut}\ L$ is determined by the image of $\sigma (a)$ and $\sigma (i)$, as $\sigma^8 (a) = 2$ and $\sigma^2 (i) = -1$ then the possibilities are

$$\sigma (a) \in \{a,-a, ai, -ai,a\xi, a\xi^3, a\xi^5,a \xi^7\} \,\,\, \text{and} \,\,\, \sigma (i) \in \{i,-i\}$$

Then there are $16$ possibilities, that is $|\mathrm {Aut}\ L| \geq 16$. Check $[L: \mathbb Q] = 16$. Then your group $\mathrm {Aut}\ L$ has order $16$. From here you need to check properties of this group.

Notice that $\mathrm {Aut}\ L$ has an element of order $8$. Then $\mathbb Z_8$ is normal in this group. Because $(\mathrm {Aut}\ L: \mathbb Z_8) = 2$, that is, has index $2$.